# Running total in Excel to a value, reset the cumulative total, and group?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, excel-tables, custom-functions-excel

I am looking to group a list of numbers based on their sums to a target value. The database is large and would need to be a scalable solution. For instance, if my target value was 10, this would look like the following:

| Item | Value | Total | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 |  | I |
| B | 3 |  | I |
| C | 4 | 11 | I |
| D | 3 |  | II |
| E | 2 |  | II |
| F | 7 | 12 | II |
| G | 10 | 10 | III |
| H | 12 | 12 | IV |

Comment: so which column are you looking for?

Comment: And if you want Group, does it have to be roman numerals or can it be just normal numbers?

Comment: I am looking for the Total and Group columns. The Group can be A, B, C, D, etc. as well or any other string. Roman numerals are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

To get the TOTAL:

```
=IF(SUM($B$2:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1)<10,"",SUM($B$2:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1))
```

To get the Group:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C1<>"",ROMAN(ARABIC(D1)+1),D1),"I")
```

Put those in C2 and D2 respectively and copy down.

[image]